# Why Pygame doesn't see keyboard presses?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I have this code:

```
        if i.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and i.moves != 0:
                ClickUnclick = 0
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        if event.button == 1:
                            displaytext = displaytext + i.symbol[0]
                            print(displaytext)
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == i.symbol[1]:
                            displaytext = displaytext + i.symbol[0]
                            print(displaytext)
```

Pygame does not respond to keyboard button presses in any way.
If anything, i is the object of my Button class used in the for loop, i.symbol is lists of two elements like this: ["0", pygame.K_0].
I've also noticed that Pygame seems to not always respond to right-click, i.e. the first condition. What can this be related to?

Comment: You might have consumed them earlier, but since we don't have a [mre], we can only guess.

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, it does happen because I've used such a loop several times. Thanks to the moderator for the link to the second question, which completely solved my problem, although I never realized what "answer" I was supposed to get from the first question they sent.